# Regex Omit and Validate

Tags: regex

I have this string

```
"<p></p>" fixed
```

Is it possible to have a regex that would omit the 7 characters and check if there are at least 3 characters in between?

```
"<p></p>" = false
"<p>   </p>" = false
"<p>Hello</p>" = true 
"<p>Hello </p>" = true
```

**Further details:-**
By default, my editor has the p tags. Therefore my validator is always returning editor string value is not empty. So I want to add the regex expression in the matches fx.

```
string().required().matches()
```

Comment: If you already have the pattern that matches your `<p>` tags, why not just negate the pattern?

Comment: I don't have a pattern yet. I'm not able to compose something that includes all the conditions. Something that would exclude the opening and closing tags and checks the in-between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exclude the opening and closing tags in between as metioned in the comments:

```
<p>(?=[^<>]{3,}<\/p>)[^<>]*[^\s<>][^<>]*<\/p>
```

**Explanation**

- `<p>` Match literally
- `(?=[^<>]{3,}<\/p>)` Positive lookahead, assert at least 3 chars other than `<` and `>` before the closing `</p>`
- `[^<>]*` Match optional chars other than `<` and `>`
- `[^\s<>]` Match a single none whitespace char other than `<` and `>`
- `[^<>]*` Match optional chars other than `<` and `>`
- `<\/p>` Match `</p>`

See a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qxtz7q/1)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you look for:

```
^<p>[\S]{3,}<\/p>$
```

if whitespaces are ok for you as well it is this one:

```
^<p>.{3,}<\/p>$
```